Can shares be recovered from a broker you can't reach?
At the risk of sounding paranoid, I'm curious about how one mitigates the risk that your country could collapse due to internal strife.
Hypothetical:
Investor owns shares in two companies (A and B), via a brokerage in their home country (the USA, if specifics are useful). Company A is located in their home country, while Company B is not (let's say Canada).
Their home country descends into utter chaos - reason agnostic (plague, civil war, zombie apocalypse, whatever) - their brokerage is a casualty of the disaster and conditions are such that recovering the contents/value of their brokerage account is a non-starter for the foreseeable future.
Investor, being a person of means, has fled their home country to the country where Company B is located.
Is there a common practice such that they could petition Company B to essentially re-issue their shares to a new brokerage account in that other country?
Please note I am NOT asking about someone whom their home country has frozen accounts or taken other deliberate/targeted actions to prevent access to their wealth.
How does one mitigate this kind of risk in portfolio planning, generally?

The easiest way to mitigate this risk is to engage a well-established broker.  Sticking to Fidelity, Vanguard, or Charles Schwab will do the trick.  This scenario is playing out with a now defunct FinTech startup.

@PeteB. Yeah, I'm curious about what happens when even they end up paralyzed or otherwise unable to answer the phone, as it were. But 'raise the bar for the triggering event' is absolutely a reasonable first step, I agree.

Questions about the end of the world are really difficult to answer reliably

If your country suddenly collapses, you are probably out of luck.  At least until things recover sufficiently that court systems can begin functioning and companies can start reconstituting themselves.
Companies know who their shareholders are.  But 99.9% of shares are held in street name which means that the shares are registered to the broker.  Company A knows that the broker holds a bunch of their shares.  But Company A has no idea who the actual beneficial owner(s) of those shares are-- only the broker knows that.  If the broker and all their backups were lost and there was no functional court system to try to resolve the ownership issues, you'd be out of luck.
If you were really paranoid about this happening (and it seems highly, highly unlikely), you could have the shares registered to you personally.  This is more work than having them held in street name, it makes trading harder, you have to manage the physical shares, etc.  But it is a thing that you could do.  Of course, in any reasonable scenario of a country collapsing you'd likely be at greater risk of your stock certificates being seized or lost than of your broker completely disappearing.  And if this is something you're alert to, it's probably much easier to electronically transfer shares from a broker in one country to a broker in another country (or relying on a broker that has an international presence) than it is to carry them from one country to another.

Saving off account statements is something that you could do to mitigate the already low risk of a broker's records all being obliterated.

@HartCO - Sure.  That would be useful evidence once court systems start functioning.  That's useful for the much more plausible scenario that a particular broker collapses taking all it's backups with it but the country and its court system remains functional to try to work through the mess.
